# Regex filtrar somente valores em real

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Tenho a seguinte regex:

```
preg_match_all('/([0-9]+[\.]*[0-9]*[\,.]*[0-9]*)/', $string, $matches)
```

Se eu receber uma string:

> 1 - João da Silva número 123456 com o valor de R$:6.298,65

Tenho como retorno:

```
array (size=27)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '123456' (length=5)
  2 => string '6.298,65' (length=8)
```

Entretanto, gostaria de ter como retorno somente o valor em real: 6.298,65

Comment: Se você adicionar `$` no final do sua regex, também funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que você esta deixando tudo como "opcional" (`*`).
A REGEX que pode lhe auxiliar é :

`~R\$:[\t ]*(\d{1,3}\.?)+(,\d{2})?~`

[Veja em REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/wCOzdE/2/)

Comment: O problema é que o valor em real nem sempre vem precedido de R$: , pode vir sem o R$: (no valor de 1.200,00) ou vir somente com o R$ (no valor de R$ 1.200,00)

Comment: @Bia se sempre tiver centavos pode alterar para `((\d{1,3}\.?)+(,\d{2}))`, [Veja](https://regex101.com/r/wCOzdE/4).

Answer (score 3):

Creio que procura o padrão `numero.numero,numero`, eu faria uma `regex` assim:

```
/\d+\.\d+,\d+/
```

- `\d` é um *shortHand* que procura por números, é o mesmo que o conjunto `[0-9]`
- `+` é um *quantificador* que procura por 1 ou mais elementos, é o mesmo que `{1,}`
- `\.` vai procurar uma string porque usei um `\`.

<sub>[***Funcionando em jsFidlle***](https://jsfiddle.net/L44g33xk/4/)</sub>
e <sub>[***Funcionando em  regex101***](https://regex101.com/r/rIJmpL/1)</sub>

Caso precise que o texto comece com você `R$:` você deve adicionar `R\$:` no começo da regex, é necessário usar o `Scape\` porque o `$` é uma borda que procura no fim do texto.